# Error on WebSocket connection to Infura Ropsten (broken close frame)

Tags: web3js, ropsten, infura, websocket

I am trying to connect to Ropsten with Web3js (1.0) via Infura using their WebSocket provider but I am getting the following error:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://ropsten.infura.io/ws' failed: Received a broken close frame containing a reserved status code.
```

This error shows up when I try to invoke a function from a contract using the `send()` method from Web3js. No issues arise at the time of creating my web3 instance, which by the way I create as follows:

```js
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider("wss://ropsten.infura.io/ws"))
```

Since the error I am getting says something related to a closed frame I tried something I found [here](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/1646) regarding the clientConfig frame size with no success:

```js
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider("wss://ropsten.infura.io/ws", {
  clientConfig: {
    maxReceivedFrameSize: 100000000,
    maxReceivedMessageSize: 100000000,
  }
}))
```

I have also seen some other threads (e.g. [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/54770/web3-websocket-connection-to-infura), [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/63606/error-in-websocket-connection), [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/49082/issue-in-websocket-connection-with-infura-using-web3)) related to WebSocket connection errors to Infura but none of them seem to be dealing with the same problem.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this
wss://ropsten.infura.io/ws/v3/YOUR-PROJECT-ID

This work for me in Ropsten

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I also tried that but didn't work. What version of Web3 are you using?

Comment: Web3 - 1.0.0-beta.34  

How I use endpoint

new Web3('wss://ropsten.infura.io/ws/v3/MyKEY')

Anyway, this works for me only on Ropsten in Mainnet not work.

Comment: Well, maybe then is something related to using version 1.0.0-beta.36. I try with beta.34 and see if this works... Thanks!

Comment: I just tried with version 34 and still doesn't work, same error :-(